# Kineticjs how to centre image on stage and resize depending on browser

Tags: resize, kineticjs, stage

I am adding an image to the stage as a background image and a rectangle. How can I ensure that the rectangle is centred on the stage and that the background resizes depending on the browser?

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:auto;"></div>
<script>
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: 1680,
height: 1050
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 239,
    y: 75,
    width: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    height: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });

  layer.add(rect);
  stage.add(layer);

var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    var myBg = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 1770,
      height: 1200,
      opacity: 0
    });

    layer.add(myBg);
    stage.add(layer);    

imageObj.src = 'img/bg.png';
  </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first,

You have a slight mistake, unless you intended it to be this way for whatever reason:

```
//these lines
layer.add(myBg); // correct
stage.add(layer);   // not correct, remove, you already have the layer on the stage, why add it again?
//instead do this:
layer.draw(); // this will just redraw the layer, since you already added the object.
```

To autosize the stage just create your stage like so:

```
 var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: window.innerWidth,  
      height: window.innerHeight
 });
```

To center an object you have to calculate its width and height compared to the stage, and place it accordingly.

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: stage.getWidth()/4,
    y: stage.getHeight()/4,
    width: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    height: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});
```

This one was simple because your rectangle is half the width and half the height of the stage.

A more complex solution, which accounts for varying sizes, is something like this:

```
    x: (stage.getWidth()/2)-(rect.getWidth()/2) // similar for height
    y: (stage.getHeight()/2)-(rect.getHeight()/2) // similar for height
```

Comment: Hi EliteOctagon, thanks for your reply. Can I use stage.getWidth and stage.getHeight also for adapting the background image to the screen size. I tried that but it does not display the image.

Comment: I found out why it was not working with the image. I had to assign to width and height `width: stage.getWidth()` and `height: stage.getHeight()`. The only problem is that the bg image does not display on safari for iPhone and iPad :( any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea. Any way you can display an error console in iOS? also, are you remembering to redraw the layer?

Comment: any other browser you can test in ? also any other mobile devices like android?